# Wistia Upload API with cURL

Tags: php, curl, wistia

Whenever I try curl in my command line using a cUrl executable and a local video file, I get a successful HTTP 200 OK.

```
curl -i -F api_password=<api_password> -F file=@C:\Downloads\Video\450730251.mp4 https://upload.wistia.com/
```

But whenever I try to use the curl executable in a live file, I can no longer get it right. I get a Couldn't Open file error.

```
curl -i -F api_password=<api_password> -F file=@http://www.dealengine.emdl.co/assets/videos/video-6ylp5m689w1.MOV https://upload.wistia.com/
```

curl: (26) couldn't open file "http://www.dealengine.emdl.co/assets/videos/video-6ylp5m689w1.MOV"

Why is this happening?

Also, whenever I try it with my code, I always get a resource #7 error and for the moment, I can't check and can only see the wistia account and I can see that nothing's uploaded.  What could I do to change the code?

Here's what I got now:

```
$data = array(
    'api_password' => '<api_password>',
    'url' => $videoFile
);

$chss = curl_init('https://upload.wistia.com');
curl_setopt_array($chss, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data)
));

// Send the request
$KReresponse = curl_exec($chss);

// Decode the response
$KReresponseData = json_decode($KReresponse, TRUE);
```

Thanks!

Comment: O.o that's a rather interesting `cURL` set up

Comment: what makes you think that curl will go and download that remote file, just so it can upload it again? curl expects a local file path, not a url. if that .mov is on your own server, then why bother with downloading it anyways? it's already on the same server...

Comment: Firstly, please stick to one question per post. Secondly, you say "I always get a resource #7 error" - please post the exact error message you get, and when you get it (e.g. which line it is triggered from).

Comment: You aren't even sending the `file` parameter to the server...

Comment: Hi Oliver and Marc B. Real sorry about this, the first code line is for when I tried doing it with an executable cURL and a local video file just to check if it's working and it did! The second one is when I tried to use it with an executable cURL like the first one but now with a live video file from the website I'm developing. It's a working URL if you try it. The third one is for when I tried executing it with the code. I get resource #7 whenever I print the variable $chss. Thanks!

Comment: Also, for @marcB, I'm trying to get it to Wistia and not just on the website's server so I thought I could test that via the command line. I am a novice in  using Wistia Upload API or even cUrl at that.

Comment: Hi @IMSoP, yes sorry. I thought it's applicable to one topic because this is all about the Wistia Upload dilemma I'm having. The first two code snippets are just my way of testing if cUrl really works for this and it did for the first command. And I actually got the Resource #7 error whenever I print the cUrl variable $chss.

Comment: @ClaerysSacal That's not an error. `$chss` is a variable representing your "cURL handle" initialised with `curl_init`; there is no data to show you, so PHP just says "it's a resource pointing at some memory; it's got an internal ID of 7". What you want to be dumping is `$KReresponse`, and also `curl_error($chss)` (see [the PHP manual](http://php.net/curl_error)).